# Creating every combination of boolean arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

A program that I'm writing needs a method that takes in three integers (say `n`, `s`, and `k`) and returns an boolean array with `s` true values, `n-s` false values, and with `k` (a variable between `0` and `n choose k`) determining their order. As an example, with the constant being `n=5`, `s=2`, and `k=1`, we could get the array

```
[true, true, false, false, false]
```

or with `n=7`, `s=3`, and `k=2`

```
[true, true, false, true, false, false, false]
```

It does not matter in particular what order `k` determines as long as its injective, i.e. different values of `k` resulting in different combinations.

One idea that I had was to use `Integer.toBinaryString(int i)` to turn each value of 'k' into a binary string and then turn the `1`s and `0`s into `true` and `false`, but unfortunately I don't see an easy way to let the number of `1`s be determined by `s`. Does anyone know a good way or can show me the right direction?

Comment: You can simply use Mod of the `k` and like if it's an odd/even no, you toggle the states.

Comment: @ADi This has now been solved, but I am still curious to see if you can clarify? I don't see how modulus can be used in this example when you have a fixed number of 1s and 0s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the [alternative I mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24640373/823393). It iterates over all n-bit numbers with only k bits set.

```
/**
 * Iterates all bit patterns containing the specified number of bits.
 *
 * See "Compute the lexicographically next bit permutation"
 * http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation
 *
 * @author OldCurmudgeon
 */
public class BitPattern implements Iterable<BigInteger> {

    // Useful stuff.

    private static final BigInteger ONE = BigInteger.ONE;
    private static final BigInteger TWO = ONE.add(ONE);
    // How many bits to work with.
    private final int bits;
    // Value to stop at. 2^max_bits.
    private final BigInteger stop;
    // Should we invert the output.
    private final boolean not;

    // All patterns of that many bits up to the specified number of bits - invberting if required.
    public BitPattern(int bits, int max, boolean not) {
        this.bits = bits;
        this.stop = TWO.pow(max);
        this.not = not;
    }

    // All patterns of that many bits up to the specified number of bits.
    public BitPattern(int bits, int max) {
        this(bits, max, false);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<BigInteger> iterator() {
        return new BitPatternIterator();
    }

    /*
     * From the link:
     *
     * Suppose we have a pattern of N bits set to 1 in an integer and
     * we want the next permutation of N 1 bits in a lexicographical sense.
     *
     * For example, if N is 3 and the bit pattern is 00010011, the next patterns would be
     * 00010101, 00010110, 00011001,
     * 00011010, 00011100, 00100011,
     * and so forth.
     *
     * The following is a fast way to compute the next permutation.
     */
    private class BitPatternIterator implements Iterator<BigInteger> {

        // Next to deliver - initially 2^n - 1

        BigInteger next = TWO.pow(bits).subtract(ONE);
        // The last one we delivered.
        BigInteger last;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if (next == null) {
            // Next one!
                // t gets v's least significant 0 bits set to 1
                // unsigned int t = v | (v - 1);
                BigInteger t = last.or(last.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
                // Silly optimisation.
                BigInteger notT = t.not();
            // Next set to 1 the most significant bit to change,
                // set to 0 the least significant ones, and add the necessary 1 bits.
                // w = (t + 1) | (((~t & -~t) - 1) >> (__builtin_ctz(v) + 1));
                // The __builtin_ctz(v) GNU C compiler intrinsic for x86 CPUs returns the number of trailing zeros.
                next = t.add(ONE).or(notT.and(notT.negate()).subtract(ONE).shiftRight(last.getLowestSetBit() + 1));
                if (next.compareTo(stop) >= 0) {
                    // Dont go there.
                    next = null;
                }
            }
            return next != null;
        }

        @Override
        public BigInteger next() {
            last = hasNext() ? next : null;
            next = null;
            return not ? last.not() : last;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported.");
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return next != null ? next.toString(2) : last != null ? last.toString(2) : "";
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Generates 1, 10, 100. One bit set in a 3-bit number.
        int bits = 1;
        int max = 3;

        System.out.println("BitPattern(" + bits + ", " + max + ")");
        for (BigInteger i : new BitPattern(bits, max)) {
            System.out.println(i.toString(2));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't run it this code now, but I accepted this answer since it looks good on inspection. I assume that if I wanted to get, for example, the sequences 001, 010, 100 (in some order), I would call BitPattern(3, 3, true) and Iterator()?

Comment: On an unrelated note: when I was learning Java, I was taught that methods shoulds start with a small letter and objects with a big letter. I see that you don't follow this, so is it a convention that should be avoided in your opinion as an experienced programmer? :)

Comment: @Sid - Added `main` to demonstrate how to get 1,010,100, you'll have to add the leading zeros yourself :) *On an unrelated note ...* - where do you see I have wandered from that? There are subtleties of that custom which state that constants should be uppercase and constructors are match their class name.

Answer (score 1):

I think the keyword you are looking for is `combinadic`.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/467492/42159) is what I finally came up with as a result of an answer to one of my questions in the Mathematics pages.

In essence you can pick the kth number in a sequence of n-bit numbers using this technique.

There's an excellent narrative on how it works in the accepted answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/467274/42159).

If, however, you are just looking to iterate through k-bit numbers there are [other more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24640473/823393) ways.

Answer (score -1):

How about shuffling the array using k to seed the Randomness?

```
myArray = [true,true,true,false,false,...]
Collections.shuffle(myArray, new Random(k))
```

Comment: That would be ideal but I can't have the same shuffled array twice for different values of k below (n choose k). Does this method avoid that?

Comment: There is a chance that different values of k could provide the same output I believe.